# Calculate $\int^{+\infty}_{x=0} e^{-x}\sin x dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This one has been tricky due to trig functions persisting in the integral, but I believe they can be ignored:

Using integration by parts I calculated as follows:

$$I = \int^{+\infty}_{x=0} e^{-x}\sin x  dx$$

$$ u = e^{-x}; du = -e^{-x}; dv = \sin x; v = -\cos x $$

$$I = -e^{-x}\cos x - \int_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\cos x$$

Integration by parts a second time:

$$ u = e^{-x}; du = -e^{-x}; dv = \cos x; v = \sin x $$

$$I = -e^{-x}\cos x - (e^{-x}\sin x + \int^{+\infty}_{x=0} e^{-x}\sin x)$$

$$I = -e^{-x}\cos x - e^{-x}\sin x - I $$

$$2I = -e^{-x}\cos x - e^{-x}\sin x$$

$$I = \frac{-e^{-x} (\cos x + \sin x)}{2} \biggr |_{x=0}^{\infty}$$

My understanding at this point is that, although the trig functions don't have a limit as x approaches infinity, they do have a ceiling on their combined possible value that is negligible due to $-e^{-x}$ dominating:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} -\frac{1}{e^x} = 0$$

So I believe the final answer should be 0, but it's not. Where, then, am I miscalculating?

EDIT:

As pointed out, I gave as the answer only the upper bound.

$$ I = \frac{-e^{-x}}{2} \frac{\cos x + \sin x}{2} \biggr |_{x=0}^{\infty}$$

$$ I = 0 - \frac{-e^0 (\cos 0 + \sin 0)}{2}$$

$$ I = 0 - \frac{-1 (1 + 0)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Write $\sin x = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$.

Comment: The contribution from the upper bound is in fact $0$, but you're missing the nonzero contribution from the $x = 0$ bound, and there's an extra factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in going from the next-to-last to last line of the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper bound as $x \to \infty$ is $0$, due to the reasons you state. However, the lower bound of the integration results at $x = 0$, that you subtract, becomes

$$-e^{-0}\left(\frac{\cos(0) + \sin(0)}{2}\right) = \frac{-1}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As such, it seems your final answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Note that [anomaly](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/156999/anomaly)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581154/calculate-int-infty-x-0-e-x-sin-x-dx#comment7362810_3581154) indicates you added an extra factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in going to your last line, which I originally had in my answer but which I've now corrected.

Comment: You've got an extra factor of $\frac12$

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for letting me know. I was correcting that, which I got from the OP's final line without noticing the mistake earlier, as you were commenting.

Comment: @saulspatz is correct, I added an extra $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @JohnOmielan, how did you get the larger latex output when building fractions? \biggr ?

Comment: @ConnerM. If you click the "edit" link, you can see exactly what I wrote. If you do that, you can see I just used the regular "\frac" MathJax command, with it appearing bigger because it's used in a separate equation line. If you want a larger fraction to appear inline (e.g., within some general text), you can use "\dfrac" instead. Also, as you asked, "\biggr" should work too, but I think using "\dfrac" is better. Note that using "\dfrac" within a separate equation has no apparent effect on the size. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

An exercise:

$\Im \displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\infty}}e^{x(i-1)}dx=$

$\Im \frac{1}{i-1}e^{x(i-1)}\big ]_0^{\infty}=$

$\Im \frac{i+1}{(-2)}e^{-x}(\cos x +i \sin x)\big ]_0^{\infty}=$

$(-1/2)e^{-x}(\cos x+\sin x)\big ]_0^{\infty}=$

$-(-1/2)(1)=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

To make your reasoning more formal, if $f(x):=e^{-x}$ has $x\to\infty$ limit $0$ while $g(x)$ is bounded for sufficiently large $x>0$, as happens when $g$ is the sine or cosine function, say $|g|\le A$ (in this case with $A=1$), $fg\to0$ too because, if you fix a large enough $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\frac{\delta}{A}$ for all $x>M$, such $x$ also satisfy $|f(x)g(x)|<\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you only made a rookie mistake of confusing the limit as the function approaches infinity with the limit of the integral as its upper bound approaches infinity, but I'll include a little explanation here anyways.

To understand why the integral as a whole wouldn't be zero, consider the first interval $(0, \pi)$ and the successive interval $(\pi, 2\pi)$ for your integrand, $f(x) = e^{-x}\sin(x)$. Now, since $$|\sin(x)| = |\sin(x+\pi)|,$$ and since $$|e^{-x}| > |e^{-(x+\pi)}|,$$ we know that $$|e^{-x}\sin(x)| > |e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi)| \longrightarrow |e^{-x}\sin(x)|-|e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi)|>0.$$
Additionally, since $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(x+\pi)$ are always of opposite signs, and since $e^{-x}$ is always positive, we know that $e^{-x}\sin(x)$ and $e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi)$ are always of opposite signs. So if $e^{-x}\sin(x)$ is greater than 0, which it is on $(0,\pi)$, then $e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi)$ is less than zero, giving us, for all $x \in (0,pi)$:
$$|e^{-x}\sin(x)|-|e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi)|>0 \longrightarrow e^{-x}\sin(x)+e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi)>0.$$
Summing up all these values, or integrating from 0 to pi, would not change this equality, so: 
$$\int_0^{\pi}e^{-x}\sin(x)+e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi) dx > 0$$
$$\int_0^{\pi}e^{-x}\sin(x)+e^{-(x+\pi)}\sin(x+\pi) dx = \int_0^{\pi}e^{-x}\sin(x)dx+ \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}e^{-(x)}\sin(x) dx = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-x}\sin(x)dx.$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-x}\sin(x)dx > 0.$$
We can apply this logic for every other interval $(2\pi n, 2\pi(n+1))$to show that the integral over each of these intervals is positive, meaning that the integral over the entire positive x axis, the sum of these integrals, must also be positive, but certainly small.

For the actual calculation of integrals like these, I like to use $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ just to make it a little easier. For this problem in particular, consider the integral $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} e^{ix}dx = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} (\cos(x) + i\sin(x))dx = i\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\sin(x)dx + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \cos(x)dx.$$
Since the actual values that come out of both $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\sin(x)dx$ and $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \cos(x)dx$ will be purely real, we know that when $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} e^{ix}dx$ evaluates to "$a+bi$", $$a=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \cos(x)dx$$ $$b=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\sin(x)dx.$$
Evaluating the integral would work in the same way you evaluate any exponential function with real coefficients:
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} e^{ix}dx = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x+ix}dx = [\frac{e^{-x+ix}}{(i-1)}]_0^{\infty} = [\frac{(1+i)e^{-x+ix}}{-2}]_0^{\infty} = \frac{-1}{2}[(1+i)(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))e^{-x}]_0^{\infty}$$ $$= \frac{-1}{2}[(\cos(x)-\sin(x))e^{-x}]_0^{\infty} +\frac{-i}{2}[(\cos(x)+\sin(x))e^{-x}]_0^{\infty}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{1}{2}.$$
So $$\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin(x)dx$$ (and as a little bonus: $\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\cos(x)dx.)$